# Put A Header On Top Of A Box In CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to put my "why you should buy from us" on top of the large grey container but don't know how to as when I centre the text the containers all shift downwards preventing the text to overlap, does anyone know a fix to this?

```css
#whybuy {
  color: #ffcc00;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}

#largebox {
  width: 1890px;
  height: 475px;
  background-color: #2c2c2c;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 200px;
}

#box1 {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #232323;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 425px;
}

#box2 {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #232323;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 325px;
}

#box3 {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #232323;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 325px;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="whybuy">WHY BUY FROM US</h1>
<div id="largebox">
  <div id="box1">
    <div id="box2">
      <div id="box3">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: how do you want it to be displayed??

Answer (score 1):

This will put your text on the largebox.

```css
#whybuy {
color: #ffcc00;
font-size: 40px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%
text-align: center;
z-index: 1;

#largebox {
  width: 1890px;
  height: 475px;
  background-color: #2c2c2c;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: relative
}

#box1 {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #232323;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 425px;
}

#box2 {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #232323;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 325px;
}

#box3 {
  height: 450px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #232323;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 325px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the margin for #largebox; it has **margin-top: 200px;**

```
 #largebox {
 width: 1890px;
 height: 475px;
 background-color: #2c2c2c;
 padding-top: 100px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 //margin-top: 200px;
}
```